# Can't rm -R directory MacOS Catalina

Tags: terminal, rm, macos-catalina

I deleted a system directory because Carbon Copy Cloner was unable to back it up and suggested replacing it. After deleting and restarting it was rebuilt by the system. However I could not delete the directory from the trash using standard methods or Terminal commands - even logged in as root. Even after disabling System Integrity Protection I had no luck.

Finder says:
The operation can’t be completed because the item “powerlog” is in use.

File was located here:

```
private>var>db>powerlog>
```

The directory that was recreated by the system contains subfolders and files but the directory in the trash has none:

```
sh-3.2# ls -la /Users/admin/Desktop/powerlog
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  3 root   wheel   96 Oct 29 16:37 .
drwx------+ 9 admin  staff  288 Nov 14 13:18 ..
```

Attempting rm -R give this result:

```
sh-3.2# rm -R /Users/admin/.Trash/powerlog
rm: /Users/admin/.Trash/powerlog: Directory not empty
```

I could not delete it after logging in as root either.

It appears no application is using the folder:

```
sh-3.2# lsof /Users/admin/.Trash/powerlog
sh-3.2#
```